# Записать сумму записей из другой таблицы в таблицу

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть 3 таблицы: **КАФЕДРЫ**, **ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ**, **ПРЕДМЕТЫ**. В таблице **ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ** есть поле *Колов_часов*, в которое нужно записывать сумму двух полей (*Колов_лекций* и *Колво_практик*) из таблицы **ПРЕДМЕТ**. Не подскажите, как это можно реализовать (можно использовать процедуры, функции, триггеры)?

```
CREATE TABLE `КАФЕДРЫ` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Номер_кафедры` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Назв_кафедры` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Номер_кафедры` (`Номер_кафедры`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Назв_кафедры` (`Назв_кафедры`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `ПРЕДМЕТЫ` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Назв_предмета` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Колво_лекций` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Колво_практик` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Лабы` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ДЗ` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Назв_предмета` (`Назв_предмета`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `ПРЕПОДАВАТЕЛИ` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ФИО` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `ID_предмета` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ID_кафедры` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Колво_часов` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Лекции` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `Практики` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `Дипломники` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Курсовики` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `ID_предмета` (`ID_предмета`),
  KEY `ID_кафедры` (`ID_кафедры`),
  CONSTRAINT `преподаватели_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_предмета`) REFERENCES `ПРЕДМЕТЫ` (`ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `преподаватели_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_кафедры`) REFERENCES `КАФЕДРЫ` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: НЕ НАДО записывать в таблицу данные, которые однозначно могут быть получены из других уже имеющихся данных. Это называется "переопределённые данные" и в большинстве случаев ведёт к проблемам несогласованности данных. Уберите это поле из структуры вообще, и считайте сумму в запросе, когда она потребуется.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь)

Comment: Крайне странная связь между предметом и преподавателем. Получается, что предмет могут вести несколько преподавателей, а каждый преподаватель - только один предмет. Очень похоже, что ваша таблица преподавателей - это нечто другое (не помню как называется, кажется курс), а вместо столбца ФИО должна быть ссылка на преподавателя.